# Compare Column Number Labels Between Dataframes in List

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of Dataframes called `r_list`. I need to remove Dataframes in this list based on whether they share column labels, which are integers 1-70. This means the output is a list of unique sets of series objects. I haven't found a solution which works, and wonder if there's a nice efficient way to do this with pandas?

```py
for cluster in r_list:
    for loc, other_cluster in enumerate(r_list):
        if (other_cluster.columns.values == cluster.columns.values).any() and (
                other_cluster.columns.values != cluster.columns.values).all():
            del r_list[loc]
```

Example dataframes:

```
[2902 rows x 2 columns],      68 70
0     S  L
1     M  L
2     M  L
3     M  L
4     M  L
...  .. ..
2897  D  M
2898  D  M
2899  D  M
2900  D  M
2901  H  I

[2902 rows x 2 columns],      70 68
0     L  S
1     L  M
2     L  M
3     L  M
4     L  M
...  .. ..
2897  M  D
2898  M  D
2899  M  D
2900  M  D
2901  I  H
```

Expected output:

```
Before: 
[(11 10)(12 14)(14 12)(18 16)(21 22)(23 26)(29 30)(31 32)(36 34)(39 40)(46 44)(56 50)(68 70)(70 68)]


After duplicates removed
[(11 10)(12 14)(18 16)(21 22)(23 26)(29 30)(31 32)(36 34)(39 40)(46 44)(56 50)(68 70)]
```

Comment: you want to remove repeated or similiar column names in a pandas dataframe?

Comment: what you have provided is a list, how does this look with the dataframe, can you also add the expected dataframe?

Comment: @anky_91 see my edit above. It's a large amount of data and I only need to compare the integer column labels. To the other question, I want to remove the second datframe compared if it contains one of the columns in the first dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand:

Input:

```
l=[(11,10),(12,14),(14,12),(18,16),(21,22),(23,26),(29,30),
     (31,32),(36,34),(39,40),(46,44),(56,50),(68,70),(70,68)]
d = pd.DataFrame(l)
print(d)
```

---

```
     0   1
0   11  10
1   12  14
2   14  12
3   18  16
4   21  22
5   23  26
6   29  30
7   31  32
8   36  34
9   39  40
10  46  44
11  56  50
12  68  70
13  70  68
```

---

Solution using `np.sort` on `axis=1`:

```
d[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(d.to_numpy(),axis=1)).duplicated()]
```

---

```
     0   1
0   11  10
1   12  14
3   18  16
4   21  22
5   23  26
6   29  30
7   31  32
8   36  34
9   39  40
10  46  44
11  56  50
12  68  70
```

If you require a list of tuples:

```
d[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(d.to_numpy(),axis=1)).duplicated()].agg(tuple,1).tolist()
```

---

```
[(11, 10), (12, 14), (18, 16), (21, 22), (23, 26), (29, 30), 
    (31, 32), (36, 34), (39, 40), (46, 44), (56, 50), (68, 70)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this approach but I need to keep the underlying dataframe in each list. Since dataframes aren't hashable, this won't work.